# ¿Cómo calcular el factorial de un número de manera recursiva en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una tarea para clase, el enunciado es el siguiente;

> Crea una Función FactorialArray (array) en la que le pasas un array de números y devuelve 1 Otro array con el factorial de cada número.
>   La función debe devolver false en caso de que el Parámetro recibido no sea una matriz o Bien alguno de los valores del array no fue un número.
>   Pista: Puedes utilizar la Función is_array () para comprobar que el Parámetro es una matriz y la Función is_int () para comprobar si un valor es un nombre entero.
>   AMPLIACIÓN: utiliza recursividad para calcular el factorial de un nombre

He hecho el siguiente código

```
<?php
function factorialArray($arrayNombre)
{
$factorials = array();

    if (is_int($arrayNombre) && is_array($arrayNombre)) {
        foreach ($arrayNombre as $numero) {
            for ($i = $numero - 1; $i > 1; $i--) {
                $numero = $numero * $i;
            }
            $factorials[] = $numero;
        }
        foreach ($factorials as $factorials){
            echo $factorials . "<br>";
        }
    }else{
        return false;
        echo "false";
    }
}


$nombres = array(15, 42, 12, 22, 77, "I");

factorialArray($nombres);
```

Mi problema es que no retorna nada, y creo que el problema reside en el IF, pero tampoco sé cómo solucionarlo... También querría pedir ayuda con lo de la recursividad, ya que no veo cómo hacerlo... Muchas gracias!

Edito con el código recursivo, hasta ahora, lo tengo así, pero sigue sin retornarme nada, y no pillo muy bien la recursividad, a ver si alguien me ayuda un poco:

```
<?php
function factorialArray($arrayNombre, $longitudArray)
{
    $factorials = array();
    for ($i = $longitudArray; $i > $longitudArray; $i--) {
        if (is_int($arrayNombre[$i])) {
            $arrayNombre[$i] = $arrayNombre[$i] * factorialArray($arrayNombre[$i] - 1, $longitudArray);
            $factorials[] = $arrayNombre[$i];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    foreach ($factorials as $factorial){
        echo $factorial . "<br>";
    }
}

$nombres = array(15, 42, 12, 22, 77);
$longitud = count($nombres);

if (is_array($nombres)){
    factorialArray($nombres, $longitud);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu principal problema reside en que la función `is_int` compara si una variable es un número **ÚNICO** es entero, y tu le estás pasando como parámetro `$arrayNombre`, el cual es un array, y por lo tanto no te muestra nada, ya que dicha condición falla.

Por otra parte, creo que estás abarcando mal el tema de la recursividad, la cual consiste en llamar a la propia función hasta que se cumpla una condición.

En este caso tienes que calcular el factorial, el cual es una secuencia en la cual se multiplican todos los números enteros desde el 1 hasta dicho número.

Te recomiendo que para casos de recursividad como este aisles el problema el cual tienes que resolver de manera recursiva (en este caso el factorial en sí) para un solo caso y después lo apliques a todos los casos para los que lo tengas que aplicar (en este caso cada uno de los elementos del array).

Dicho esto, la función factorial de manera recursiva quedaría así:

```
function factorial($numero)
{
    if($numero >= 2){
        return ($numero * factorial($numero - 1));
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Es decir, lo que hacemos en esta función es pasarle un número como parámetro y, si este es mayor o igual que 2 (multiplicar por 1 va a ser el mismo número así que nos evitamos dicho cálculo), devolvemos el número multiplicado por el siguiente resultado de la función factorial pasándole como parámetro el número menos 1.

De esta manera, cuando el siguiente numero entero sea menor que 2, devolveremos `true` para que devuelva el número obtenido. Si devolviéramos `false` nos devolvería 0.

Por último, lo aplicaremos al array:

```
$numeros = array(15, 42, 12, 22, 77, "I");

foreach($numeros as $numero){
    if(is_int($numero)){
        echo number_format(factorial($numero),0,'','') . "\n";
    }
}
```

Fíjate que le aplico la función `is_int` a cada uno de los elementos del array por separado y no al array completo.

**Nota:** Utilizo la función `number_format` para obtener el número completo ya que para números muy altos, por ejemplo para el factorial de 77, si no te lo va a mostrar de manera exponencial.

Comment: Buenos días! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he entendido bastante bien el procedimiento, pero me encuentro con un problema un poco chorrada... Verás, al ejecutar "echo number_format(factorial($numero),0,'','') . "\n";" me encuentro con la comprobación de "is_array($numero)", evidentemente me dice que $numero no es un array sino simplemente un número... Se te ocurre cómo podría hacer la comprobación? Muchas gracias, a la que resuelva esto te marco como respuesta buena! ^^

Comment: @THR4SH3RP0L0 Realmente si quieres hacer la comprobación de `is_array`, esta la tendrías que aplicar antes de realizar el `foreach`, es decir, `if(is_array($numeros)){ foreach....}`. De esta manera, te aseguras que `$numeros` sea un array antes de realizar el `foreach`.

Comment: Es lo que había pensado, pero el problema es que, entonces, en la parte de $numero = $numero * factorial(), a la función factorial tendría que pasarle el array entero, y los cálculos no serían correctos, me equivoco?

Comment: De hecho, éste es el error que me tira: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\untitled\exercici2.php on line 10

Comment: he actualizado con el código con recursividad tal como lo tengo ahora, a ver si le ves alguna solución...

Comment: @THR4SH3RP0L0 Sí, realmente estás planteando mal mi solución. La cuestión es que la parte recursiva la tienes que tener en cuenta como si la fueras a hacer para un solo número (de momento olvídate del array). Entonces lo que vas a hacer va a ser llamar a la función dentro de la propia función (definición de función recursiva). Es decir, cuando llames a `factorial(5)` lo que va a devolver es `5 * factorial(4)`, `20 * factorial(3)` y así sucesivamente hasta que se cumpla la condición de que el número que pasa como parámetro sea menor que 2, que es cuando devolverá el resultado.

Comment: @THR4SH3RP0L0 Después simplemente consiste en llamar a dicha función recursiva para cada uno de los números (el bucle foreach) y que vaya mostrando el factorial de cada número. Ten en cuenta de que hasta que la función recursiva de un número no acabe no pasará a realizar la del número siguiente. Espero que ahora te quede un poco más claro :)

Comment: Todo claro, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si compruebas una array `[]` si es un número con `is_int($arrayNombre)` te saldrá siempre `false`.

He cambiado algunas cosas en tú código (está comentado):

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1576ef38085454225d2293a6fee6f1da12af730)**</kbd>

```
<?php

function factorialArray( $arrayNombre ) {

  $factorials = array();

  // Aquí comprobamos si es un array
  if ( is_array( $arrayNombre ) ) {

    foreach ( $arrayNombre as $numero ) {

      // Aquí comprobamos si es un número `int`
      if ( is_int( $numero ) ) {

        for ( $i = $numero - 1; $i > 1; $i-- ) {
          $numero = $numero * $i;
        }

        $factorials[] = $numero;
      }
      else {
        // Mostramos en pantalla el error 
        echo 'No es un número'.PHP_EOL;;
      }
    }

    foreach ( $factorials as $factorials ) {            
        echo $factorials.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
  else {        
    return false;
  }
}

$nombres = array( 15, 42, 12, 22, 77, "I" );    
factorialArray( $nombres );
```

Comment: Creo que te olvidaste de la parte de la recursividad que hacía referencia en su pregunta.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero - No lo he olvidado.. ni he comprobado si esta bien el resultado... simplemente le he solucionado el problema principal....